# Create a Call for an representation User in Skype for Business / Lync using the Lync SDK

Tags: c#, lync, skype-for-business

we want to start a call for another Location using the Lync SDK. We have for each Location a specific User. Always when the specific user start a Call the outgoing Number is set to the Number of the Location. Now we want to start the Call using a C# application. Is there a solution to start a Call as an other User using the SDK? In the Skype for Business Client we have the Option right click -> Call -> For User XY.

Is there a way to use this function or how can we otherwise realize it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean making a call for a [Lync client Delegate](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Perform-as-someone-s-delegate-9baaf25e-1078-4137-9251-da4f999e97e1)?

To make a call on byhalf of another user (i.e. the current user has been setup as a Lync Delegate of another user) then you use the [LyncClient.DelegatorClients](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.lync.model.lyncclient.delegatorclients_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncclnt.aspx) property to enumerate all the current users delegate users picking the one you want and use the DelegatorClient as you would the LyncClient to make a call.

This is exactly what the Lync Client is doing when you use the "For User X" calls.